# PHP5-FPM static, dynamic or on demand?

Tags: php, nginx

I have a Nginx + PHP5-FPM server with few high traffic websites.

From my understanding of PHP5-FPM pools config, I understood that:

static = can be used to immediately create N child processes so they do not need to be opened/re-opened, they are already opened and can be used when needed, else they are "sleeping".

dynamic = can be used to open a limited number of child processes and re-spawn then when a limit is reached (min/max servers).

ondemand = I specify the max number of child processes to create, and then child processes are created on demand, when needed, and closed when not needed anymore, maintaining a low memory usage but increasing the response time of few milliseconds.

From my tests with a high traffic WordPress website, I noticed that:

If I use "static", the website is for sure faster and can handle immediately high number of concurrent connections, but the memory always increases its usage, and after N hours it seems to use almost the total RAM available. So I have to use a cronjob to periodically (every 1 hour) reload PHP5-FPM with /etc/init.d/php5-fpm reload.

If I use "dynamic" it uses less RAM but after N concurrent connections there are frequent 502 errors (but maybe I configured it not well).

If I use "ondemand" the site is a little slower (like +50/100ms response time), but it can handle all the high traffic without using too much RAM.

So my personal conclusion would be that "ondemand" is really the best method to use in terms of low/controlled memory usage, the only downside is the +50/100 ms in response time but in my case it is not a big problem.

Are my assumptions correct ?

Comment: Sidenote: you can set `pm.max_requests` to have PHP-FPM restart workers after X requests to work around the memory leak without using cron, and yes Ondemand with a sufficient amount of workers started immediately is good.

Comment: "but the memory always increases its usage" --- how exactly do you check that?

Comment: André I noticed that even with pm.max_requests set to 50 the memory increases (Wordpress + Custom Theme + 20 plugins loaded).

Comment: zerkms I check the memory with "top" and after 30 minutes from /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart I see the memory increased of like 5GB with almost no traffic. I know the problem may be related to WP plugins eating the memory or poorly coded of course, but I just noticed that using ondemand helps in maintaining the memory usage very low compared to static.

Comment: @user2972081 better use a bigger number for `pm.max_requests` like `500` or `1000`

Answer (score 7):

You didn't mention WHY you would want to keep memory low. Assuming this machine is dedicated to serving PHP-FPM, keeping memory low doesn't help your application in anyway. You have memory, use it.

Therefore, in this case, "static" is the best choice, with max_requests set to something that will keep memory leaks (if you have any) under control.

If this machine is shared with other tasks, then keeping memory low is ideal. In this case, "dynamic" is the best compromise between speed and memory usage.

"ondemand" is a good choice only when the PHP-FPM engine will be used infrequently and the machine's primary purpose is something else.

Answer (score 5):

You can configure PHP-FPM to restart automatically by detecting if children processes die within a determined period of time.

In the global configuration "php-fpm.conf" you can set to restart PHP-FPM if 5 child proccess die within 1 minute and wait for 10 seconds before that happens.

```
// php-fpm.conf
emergency_restart_threshold = 5
emergency_restart_interval = 1m
process_control_timeout = 10s
```

So you can continue using "dynamic" without using cron.